# Move the whole installed files to another partition

Tags: installation, re-installation

I have installed ubuntu on a <s>8GB</s> 5GB partition. As I have installed many packages, I am running out of space.

Qn 1 : Is there a way that I can specify another portion for installing the packages ?

Qn 2 : Can I move the whole installed files from my current partition to another place ( partition ) and make the changes in grub or so?

I don't want to reinstall the whole, so after that I just can make an upgrade :-)

The / , and home directory is in same place.

Thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1: no, it's not possible. The paths are fixed.

A2: if you want to move files to another partition, you'll need to use a Live CD. Please consider resizing partitions first which is much easier and less error-prone. This is only possible if you've enough space on one disk. Consider moving your `/home` folder as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539#50539) too, 8GB should be enough for `/` in most cases. If you want to use a second disk as root partition or wish to create a new partition on the current disk, please continue.

1. Make a backup (preferably with disk-cloning software like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)).
2. Boot into the Live CD, do not mount anything
3. Create a new partition using the Disk Utility or GParted. This partition must support Linux file permissions. Such a filesystem is ext4. Label it "UbuntuRoot" so you can find the partition easier, otherwise you'll have to remember the partition name (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`)
4. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run `sudo blkid` to get the UUID for your newly created partition. Example output, you'll need the last line:

   ```
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="HDD" UUID="AD078BC9C024FCDD" TYPE="ntfs"
   /dev/sda2: LABEL="DATA" UUID="FDE43758913E70EE" TYPE="ntfs"
   /dev/sda3: UUID="a88638ae-3cd3-45c0-ad06-2d56d89b19a0" TYPE="swap"
   /dev/sda4: UUID="e3f848cb-5a05-4d2d-92e0-3eaf7b27338c" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/sdb1: LABEL="UbuntuRoot" UUID="1cdfadcf-0969-48ba-96a5-42557c23f8e9" TYPE="ext4"
   ```
5. Mount your old root partition (`/dev/sdb1` is your newly created partition, `/dev/sda4` was your old partition):

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/old
   sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/old
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
   ```
6. Copy over the files (this may take a while):

   ```
   sudo cp -prvT /media/old /mnt
   ```
7. Update `/mnt/etc/fstab` with the new UUID. Pick an editor at your choice:

   ```
   sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab
   gksu gedit /mnt/etc/fstab
   ```

   Find the line that looks like and replace the UUID of `/dev/sda4` with the `/dev/sdb1`'s UUID:

   ```
   # / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
   UUID=e3f848cb-5a05-4d2d-92e0-3eaf7b27338c /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   ```
8. Save `/mnt/etc/fstab` and exit the editor. Next, GRUB needs to be updated to boot from the new disk and partition.

   ```
   sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
   ```
9. Unmount the partitions to finish it:

   ```
   sudo umount /mnt /media/old
   ```
10. Reboot to check the result.

Comment: Thank You for your quick reply on it. I will try and write the experience :-)

Comment: It was 5 GB only, not 8 GB.

Comment: 5GB is a bit low but will suffice if you're cleaning files regularly (`sudo apt-get clean` to clear your APT caches, browser cache). I've a fresh development installation here using only 3G including a `/home` of 200MB.

Comment: Sorry man , I went into trouble . Not sure how I lost my bootloader . And it was coming in the grub-rescue> terminal ( Before I tried your steps). But I went with the USB and tried your steps hoping the bootloader will install it. But all the error came when I tried to install the bootloader . I tried different ways . In yours it says root, but in the help I see boot , so to conclude these were the errors http://pastie.org/2370460 . But I had a fresh install on another partition . So now I have 2 Ubuntu :) . Anyway as the data is safe I am happy with it.

Comment: Read the manual if you're not sure what an option is used for. `--boot-directory` sets the location in which GRUB's files are placed. By default, this is `/boot/grub` (`/mnt/boot/grub`). I assume `/dev/sda11` is your target partition? Otherwise, could you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid`?

Comment: Yes `sda11` it was my target which was mounted on `/mnt`. The other one was `sda10` which was mounted on the `/media/old` as you suggested .

Comment: This is the `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l` http://pastie.org/2370527

Comment: I've updated the instructions: the partition number from step 8 must be omitted.

Comment: Oh so `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` in my case, but as I have done with it, this may help some others. Sometimes I forgot how to install the bootloader . And I hope this will be same if we lost a bootloader when booting from live CD. I would like to know if there is any anyother way also ? Thank you for the replies :) .

Comment: That's the command you'll need (do not forget to `sudo mount /dev/sda11 /mnt` before). It works both from the Live CD and a regular session though the Live CD is generally recommended for such tasks. What do you mean by "another way"?

Comment: Another way I was looking was without booting from Live CD, in fedora and all there is a command line , we can just tell to install grub from the terminal . Wondering if there was something like that.

Comment: Are you talking about the GRUB shell or recovery mode? You said that your system wouldn't boot anymore and droppped to a GRUB shell. So, recovery mode does not make sense. I don't know if it's possible to install `/boot` from such a shell.

Comment: Yes `grub-rescue` was showing. I wonder we can do something from that also ? The other one is we insert a disk and when it starts booting there is an option to install grub in previous versions of Fedora not sure about todays case. And it will enter into a shell and we can issue certain commands to install the grub. Ok no issues and Thank you .

Comment: I wrote a script [Clone Ubuntu to new partition](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028605/307523), that does what your answer states.