# Transfering files from Windows 7 to Ubuntu VIA partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs, fat32

Is it possible to transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows by creating a partition? Like a flash drive would work (mounting the partition, copying the files to it, then mounting and copying on the other OS), but inside my hard drive. I know I couldn't transfer folders because Ubuntu uses fat32 and Windows uses NFTS, but what about normal files? And what file type should I use to format the partition? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and dual-boot with WUBI, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Follow these answers: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/54219/164718) and [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/325118/164718)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you boot into *Ubuntu*, you can access to your *Windows* partition directly... You can manage your *Windows* files from *Ubuntu*... What you CAN'T do, is accessing *Ubuntu* partition from *Windows*... What you can do, is making a partition with a **NTFS** format... So, you can access it from *Windows* and *Ubuntu* as well...

Hope it helps...

Comment: You can download a program for windows that allows Windows to read ext2/3/4 partitions. Here a 3 examples of the software: [3 Ways to Access Your Linux Partitions From Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/)