# How to move my files from Windows Vista to Ubuntu as I have both on my pc and I want to remove vista?

Tags: backup, windows-vista

I want to remove Windows Vista from my PC so I want to transfer all my files to Ubuntu, 
I haven't tried any thing yet, only want to know if there is a quick and easy way of doing it.

Comment: copy your file from vista included partition to another one and format vista partition, after you may want grub update

Answer (score 1):

Normally your Windows partitions are automatically mounted at startup of Ubuntu, and you can easily transfer files between Windows and Ubuntu, but if anything goes wrong, don't panic, you can make through this way:

**Find the disk drivers**

First of all, you have to find your windows' partitions, to do so, run this command:

```
fdisk -l
```

it gives you a list of partitions available, windows' partitions are NTFS formatted, find the partition you want to transfer files from, let's say it's `/dev/sda3` for example.

**Check if the partition is mounted**

Now you have see if the partition you want to transfer files from is mounted or not, to do so, run this command and replace `/dev/sda3` with the one you found:

```
mount | grep /dev/sda3
```

if any result comes out, it's mounted and you know where it is mounted, for example my result was:

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/mahdi/Gamez type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

If the partition wasn't mounted and your `mount | grep /dev/sda3` gave no result, mount the drive to a folder, it can be any empty folder you want!

For example you can make a folder called "windows" and mount the windows partition on it this way:

```
mkdir /media/windows
mount /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

**Transfer Files**

The easiest step, uh. Just copy the files from the mounted partition to your Ubuntu partitions and there ya go!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view and copy all your files while booted into ubuntu since ubuntu can read and write to ntfs partitions. Otherwise just copy to a external and move them that way.