# Backup and restore all application to fresh ubuntu install

Tags: apt, backup

I want to backup all my installed applications so that I can use them in fresh installation of Ubuntu (12.04 as of now) later. 
[APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/) only picks up .deb ( at `/var/cache/apt/archives`)  but I have installed packages by downloading from the internet. What I want to backup all my applications and configurations so that I do not have to go through the hurdle again.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54217/move-the-whole-installed-files-to-another-partition) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) are useful but I guess solution to my problem is simpler than this.

**Why can't I backup all everything within the root (`/`)** and then when ubuntu is installed fresh just copy all the files to the new `/` and then do `sudo apt-get update` and update `grub` and `etc/fstab`?  Please help this newbie to understand this.

Comment: Have you compiled/installed any packages from source that are not in the repositories?

Comment: Yes. I could not found `texstudio` in `/var/cache/apt/archives` although its there and I use it

Answer (score 0):

Try [Aptik](https://launchpad.net/apt-toolkit).

To install it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Comment: Will look at it...