# post installation /home partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, home-directory

i installed ubuntu 1st with the default partitions and now i want to migrate to a  swap boot home ... partition layout.is it possible to change that after the installation ?

Comment: Moving home to another partition can be done the same way as was [answered here for moving to a different disk](http://askubuntu.com/q/21321/3940)

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You can use `gparted` to create a new partition schema. You can change the size of partitions and create new ones. Make sure you backup your data before just in case something goes wrong.

Don't forget to apply the corresponding changes to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: my question is the same: if i had home directory and system on one partition named "Linux Partition", can i safety move /home to another partition, splitting "Linux Partition"?

Comment: @loldop Not in one step. First you create the new partition, then you copy the data from `/home` to the new partition, then you delete `/home/*` and finally you mount the partition to `/home`.

Comment: good, when i create new partition, this partition will be formatting? so, i lost all data? or not?

Comment: Creating a partition does not erase data. When you delete a partition the data stored on the filesystem will be lost. Resizing a partition with gparted will not erase the data on it.

Comment: good, so, it is logic partition, and doesn't change data, that stored physically, when it resized. thanks!