# Installing Ubuntu on a 16 GB SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, system-installation

I'm pretty new to Linux, and I'm trying to make a dual boot now to try to learn it.
But I'm having some difficulties because I want it in a pretty weird way.
First of all, my laptop has 3 drives, a 16 GB mSata SSD, a 120 GB SSD and a 1 tb (900 GB) HDD, the 120 GB SSD I use for Windows 8, and the 1 tb drive has a 800 GB partition for my data in windows, and a 100 GB partition I want to use for Ubuntu data.

What I'm trying to accomplish is: I want to install/boot Ubuntu from my 16 GB SSD, but store everything except for the system files on the 100 GB partition, so it'll boot fast, and I've got enough space for my programs, is this possible and if so, how? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/how-do-i-use-my-home-directory-on-a-separate-partition

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is when installing, you choose "Something else" when it comes to make partition, as you don't want to use the entire disk. Basically, you will make your partitions manually.

When you make your partition:
Mount your 16Gb as /

Mount around 4Gb of your 100 Gb partition as Swap

Mount the remaining 96 Gb of this 100 Gb partition as /home

Normally, 16Gb is more than enough for a normal use of Ubuntu. Now, if you are planing to install A LOT (and I mean really A LOT) of software, games, etc, you may add another partition on your 100 Gb, which you will mount as /usr. I would not suggest you to do this, because it may make your system slower, as all your apps will be on a mechanical HD. To give you an idea, my partition / is only 20Gb, and it is more than enough, as I use around 10Gb, and I have a lot of software and games installed.