# how to install ubuntu and applications in separate partition

Tags: partitioning, clonezilla

I what to format my computer such that both the os and all additional applications are going in one partition and all of my person files in a second one. The reason for that is that I can then create a ghost based on the first partition only and therefore save a lot of space. Alternatively, I would like some help on how to create a ghost that doesn't consider specific folders under my home directory (i.e. my personal files). Any ideas?

Comment: Backing up your OS and apps seems pointless IMHO. Backup the settings for your apps sure but the binaries? Why bother when you have a package manager which can re-install everything again in a few minutes anyway?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352 - you want `/` on one partition and `/home` on another.

Comment: Use murus link or this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/how-do-i-use-my-home-directory-on-a-separate-partition they do what you want

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is you can't. because Linux uses [filesystem hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). And there isn't only one path for storing application's data.

However, most space for data is on /usr directory but for your case, it doen'st help you for seperating it because some config files will leave out and you'll end up with package confliction.