# Install applications on a mechanical disk other than the SSD?

Tags: ssd, 19.04

*Good day*, I have a mechanical disk and an SSD, in the SSD I have installed the operating system ubuntu 19.04 and all the software. How can I install software such as wireshark and other applications on the mechanical disk since I am running out of space on the SSD?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [file `/etc/fstab`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) to decide which elements of your filesystem get stored on which storage hardware. In other words, you only get to choose which *directories* get stored on which disk.

Since many applications install files in multiple locations across your filesystem, you generally don't get to decide on an application-by-application basis. There are a few exceptions to this, like AppImages and Flatpacks.

For most folks it's simplest to [migrate your `/home` directory to the HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283060/). It's often the biggest space-consumer anyway. For example, of the 26G used on my 30G SSD, 23% is my /home.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks!!