# Is Edubuntu a Complete Network Package?

Tags: edubuntu

I'm on the board of small private (Christian) school in Houston, TX.  We were recently given 10 PC's with erased hard drives. I am currently an Ubuntu user. Would Edubuntu allow me to set up these PC's so that any student can log in on any machine and see his/her home directory on a central hard disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on the condition that this central hard disk is formatted as ext. Using NTFS is not advisable(/possible) since NTFS does not recognize permissions as Linux expect them when dealing with /home/. See [Is it bad to have /home/ on an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330356/is-it-bad-to-have-home-on-an-ntfs-partition) for some more problems you might face (like Linux makes a difference between capital and small letters).

You can of course also opt to link the directories in /home/$USER/ to a central disk and have /home/ itself reside on the partition where the OS resides.

But this is normal for any Linux, not just Edubuntu or Ubuntu.

Edubuntu in itself is the same as Ubuntu but the default desktop software installed is targeted on Education. The difference are solely on the desktop. The inner working (ie. mounting of discs, settings etc etc) are still the same.