# Can I hide files so that they are hidden on both Windows and Linux?

Tags: filesystem

I have my computer set up to use the same home folder / user profile for Linux and Windows. As a consequence I have files like `NTUSER.DAT` that are hidden on Windows showing up when I `ls` and in my file manager. Is there any way to make Linux hide the hidden files?

Comment: You have a secondary consequence: Using NTFS for your Linux home directory will break Linux permissions because NTFS does not support them.

Answer (score 21):

Add the files you want to hide to a file named `.hidden` with 1 file per line inside the directory those files are. Somehing like `ls {files} >.hidden` will work to quickly do this.

- You can hide files looking from Windows with `C:\>attrib +h D:\*.hidden /S` (this will hide the `.hidden` file from the previous method). The directory I assumed D:.
- You can hide these files from `ls` on Linux by adding this into your `~./bashrc`:

  ```
  ls () {
    if [ -f .hidden ]; then
      declare GLOBIGNORE="$GLOBIGNORE:.*:$(tr '\n' ':' < .hidden)"
      ls "$@"
    fi
  }
  ```

  This will hide the files when using `ls` and `ls` only. It also assumes you do not already have an alias for `ls`. `ls -l` will still show them but that is just another alias.

---

The last command I found on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/816004/276585http://). Please upvote *that* answer ;)

Comment: Hmmm... if I understand well, the OP is thinking using an NTFS filesystem as home dir... they should read your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330356/is-it-bad-to-have-home-on-an-ntfs-partition

Comment: will this work for graphical file managers too?

Comment: For nautilus yes, only the 1st part is needed for that. The 3rd part is for command line. Not sure about other managers though. The .hidden method might be Nautilus feature.

Comment: `attrib` will only work on NTFS/FAT filesystems.

Comment: @Rinzwind It causes other problems though: if you try to run `ls -l` `bash` passes the `-l` flag to the las `export` :(

Comment: “please upvote” ITYM downvote, that code didn't have a chance of doing anything useful except when `ls` was called with no argument in a directory containing a `.hidden` file and the code to restore `GLOBIGNORE` didn't work at all.

Comment: This sounded interesting...until I realized that executing the Windows command into the Linux WSL home folder is not possible: it's part of the linux image and is not visibile from outside. You can do the opposite with /mnt/C, but it doesn't solve the problem :Y

Comment: wsl does not work as a normal linux so can likely not be used,