# Ubuntu Server SSD primary OS, user data/home folders on secondary RAID1

Tags: raid, home-directory, ssd

I have a 60GB SSD drive that i want Ubuntu Server 13 installed upon, and user home folders (except for root) automatically redirected to a secondary RAID1 array. Each hard drive in the array is 2TB. When creating the user accounts, i know i can specify where the home folders are. However, i'd like for the /home folder to point to the RAID1 array.

I had the OS installed on the RAID1 array just fine, then the update to 13.10 killed it. I've since come into 2 60GB SSD drives and i want to use one of them for the OS and the RAID1 array to host user home folders. Eventually, i'll add SMB sharing to the RAID1 array as well, but migrating the user home folders to the array is primary concern.

How can i set this up?

Answer (score 0):

You just mount the file system on the RAID array via UUID in `/etc/fstab` as `/home`. It's pretty straight forward, given that you RAID array is properly detected during boot when the kernel mounts the file systems from `fstab`.

See: [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539#50539)

Comment: The link given is for a different partition (sdb1), but i'm assuming specifying a different disk and partition will behave the same way. is that correct? thanks for your help so far.

Comment: That should be correct.