# On which hard-drive is the home folder? (Using a USB Boot Disk)

Tags: boot, disk-usage

First time using linux/ubuntu, so pardon the noobiness.

I created a boot disk and booted from it using the 'try' method. I've barely done anything and I'm getting error messages stating that I have low disk space (on the desktop/home folder). AFAIK, I have no *real* disk space issues so I presume it's some kind of partitioning matter (though I really don't know).

When I try to trace back directories on the home folder - I can't get beyond "File System" or "Home", and when I try to get some indication from Gparted I can not find any drive labeled 'Home' or the like.

How do I find where the home folder is located? How can I re-partition it or somehow increase its potential size?

This is driving me absolutely nuts. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to open the `System Monitor` by clicking the dash icon (top left) and entering System Monitor as the search. When it opens, click the File Systems tab and it will show you where everything is placed.

[image]

/dev stands for device. HDDs will normally be named SDA, SDB, SDC, etc.

[image]

The above shows 3 HDDs and 1 DVD rom. My linux installation is on HDD "b" (Hence, dev/sdb) and includes 3 partitions, one for Root "/dev/sdb/", one for boot "/dev/sdb/boot" and one for home "/dev/sdb/home".

**A second way** of determining would be to use `fdisk`. Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>), enter `sudo fdisk -l` and input your password when prompted. It will output your drives and how they are configured.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. James :-) Nice and simple. Unfortunately, when I check out System Monitor, there is no drive listed with /home directory beside it (as in yours). See here: http://i.imgur.com/2MB9Mxq.png

Comment: @user220601 this means that your /home is part of root.

Comment: @hildred Ok. Then I guess my original problem and question now applies to "root".

Comment: looking at the screenshot you provided your root filesystem is on a union filesystem where there are two under filesystems, a read only filesystem on the cd and a read/write filesystem which I think is on your usb drive. you appear to have space on another drive, but I don't know which is which, so It is time for some old fashion system administration, either setting up a partition for home on another drive or creating a directory for home on another partition and using a symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Ok, I'll have a go at moving my home folder using these steps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive if this doesn't work, I am ready to give up on ubuntu for now. I don't understand why I'm having the low disk space error, and I can't even get a good look at this home/root directory to see which drive it's on or how much space there is. This seems like it should be a simple matter - I don't understand why it's been so difficult so far.

Comment: Well it didn't work for me. I couldn't access "System->Administration->Users & Groups". Assuming this was from a previous version, I tried "System->User Accounts" but could not make any modifications to "My Account" or "Other Accounts". ...What a drag this has been.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal

```
df /home
```

or for another path

```
df /some/other/path
```

If you have more than 2 drives, you can check this by running `df some_path` for a path on each drive.  When you do this, `df` should return different responses for the different paths on different drives.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up a terminal and type df and press enter. This will give a list of all drives, how much free space they have and where they are mounted. your home directory is probably in the form of /home/*username*/ where *username* is your username. If you have a separate drive for home directories it will probably be mounted on /home, but based on how your question was asked, I suspect that everything is on the flash drive and it is almost full, and that your next question will be how do I move my home directory to a different drive.

Comment: Thanks for your response, hildred. Unforunately when I enter "du", the only responses I get are "./.cache/..." and "./Desktop/..." (no /home/<username>/). See my other comment for an image of space on my flash drive. I had looked at moving my home directory before asking this question, but decided I'd like to locate it first.

Comment: oops. my typo I ment df not du.

Comment: Ah. Well here is my situation for df, if you care to see: http://i.imgur.com/Z7yQQfP.png Once again, no obvious "/home" sector.