# Repartitioning in 14.94 To Add Home Partion

Tags: partitioning

I have 32 bit 14.04 installed as the only OS on a older Toshiba Laptop.  Unfortunately, when I installed it I did not set up a \home partition, which I had intended to do.  What I want to do is to set up a \home partition and to transfer the files in my current \home directory to it.

I have a 14.04 Live CD, so I could reinstall 14.04.

I also have GParted on a Live CD.

If I use GParted, I need precise instructions about how to proceed.

I have plenty of disk space (200 GB) for either alternative and know how to decide space allocation for Linux partitions.

How should I proceed?

Thanking you in advance.

```
 Chaim Frazer
```

Comment: post the screenshot of gparted partition editor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinstall Ubuntu, but you do need to boot off of a Live CD.

1. From the Live CD, open up GParted.
2. Right-click on the ext4 Ubuntu partition and resize it. This will probably take up most of your hard drive. Shrink this partition as appropriate. Note that the changes won't be applied immediately.
3. In the free space that appears, right-click and create a new ext4 partition. This will be your `/home` partition.
4. Apply the changes (this is the check mark icon, if I recall correctly).
5. Boot into Ubuntu. In case there are any boot issues, use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

The next steps are to move your files from `/home` to the other partition, and to have a directory in the other partition be recognized as `/home`. See the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/50539/241580) or [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving#Find_the_uuid_of_the_Partition) for this.