# Can you help me mount a new home directory or similar?

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox

I have a virtualbox with host windows 8 and guest ubuntu 14. Now my disk space is running out and I'm reluctant to doing the complicated partition resizing which doesn't seem completely safe.

I've previously asked about resizing here https://askubuntu.com/questions/620051/how-can-i-resize-a-virtualbox-guest-os-ubuntu

Now it was mentioned that instead of resizing I could try a) cleaning up my system but that didn't help enough. I deleted files from an old installtion of altera quartus ii but it didn't free enough space.

What I need to do is import a large backup into mongo (> 2 GB that also needs some temporary space).

So I wonder if there is any way to mount a new partition from where I can import my large backup?

Any other advice what I can do but creating an entire new ubuntu image with larger space that is likely to consume all of my system space?

Comment: Your question title and body are not very consistent.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive - you just create another VDI, attach it to your VM, format it, and [mount it via fstab on boot](http://askubuntu.com/a/620437/3940).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily in simple method, just create another VDI hdd in your virtual machine and attach it to your machine, then boot your ubuntu, once you login you can see the icon of an external hdd on your unity launcher.

click it and thus it's mounted now so you can easily copy or move whatever you want to it.

This tricky method as you are using external hdd on your machine.

If you want to make this persistent you have to add it  to the `/etc/fstab`.

```
 UUID=/your-new-hdd-UUID /mounting-point FileSystem-used    defaults    0   0
```