# How to create a separate home partition after installing Ubuntu under single / partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have got a dual boot system here with a couple of partitions:

- Windows 7 OS partition
- Another partition for office data
- One partition for Ubuntu
- And of course one 100Mb partition auto-made by Windows
- And just like Windows one swap partition by Ubuntu

Of course, I wanted to have a separate partition for `/boot` and `/home` which I have not got here, so I would like to do that if it’s possible.
Can I install GParted in my system and create a new partition by shrinking my existing `/` partition, then mount `/home` under it somehow? I don't want to mess up my system. Some concrete advice required here.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don’t create a separate home partition while installing Ubuntu, you don’t have to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. To migrate to a separate home partition after installation, you’ll have to create a new partition (which may require resizing your existing partitions), copy the files from your existing home directory to that partition, and tell Ubuntu to mount the new partition at /home.

1. **Create a New Partition :** use Gparted to shrink and create new partition. Here a [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) for you.
2. **Copy Home Files to New Partition** : copy your files from old home to the newly created partition

   ```
   sudo cp -Rp /home/* /new-partition-mount-point
   ```
3. **Get your new Partition’s UUID**: use the command:

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   Copy the UUID to add it later to the `fstab`
4. **Add to the fstab**:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   Add the following text to the fstab file on a new line

   ```
   UUID=New-partition-UUID    /home     ext4     nodev,nosuid     0     2
   ```
5. **Move Home Directory & Restart**

   Move your current home directory, and create a new, empty home directory which your new partition will be mounted at:

   ```
   cd / 
   sudo mv /home /home_OLD
   sudo mkdir /home
   ```

Now restart and check your new configuration, If everything is just perfect then you can completely remove your old home.

```
sudo rm -rf /home_OLD
```

For details and more information refer to the Ubuntu wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving