# Error mounting disk drive

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

[image: Error screenshot]

One of my partition is showing up this error when opening. I removed windows today and installed Ubuntu in the 128GB SSD. After starting Ubuntu, I am not able to open my secondary HDD partition. I tried so many ways to fix it, many commands, still no luck. Can someone help me with this please? I have attached the screenshot of the error.

I have removed Windows, so going to Windows and turning off fast boot is not an option for me, like suggested in many threads online.

Comment: So you're saying your Windows was on HDD ( which is where your partition that you can open ) or SSD ? Is there a possibility of completely formatting that HDD ? If there's files , try backing them up somewhere like a USB drive, and formatting that partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition was not cleanly unmounted the last time it was used. Unfortunately, because it's NTFS, this problem ***cannot*** be fixed within Ubuntu; you ***must*** fix it from Windows. You can (temporarily) move the disk to a Windows computer, use a Windows emergency repair disk, or re-install Windows on the disk to fix the problem.

Once the problem is fixed, if you intend to keep using your computer as Ubuntu-only, you should back up the data on the partition in question, convert the partition to a Linux-native filesystem (ext4fs, btrfs, XFS, etc.), and restore the data; or back up the data, delete the partition, expand your Ubuntu partition, and restore the data. Using NTFS on a Linux-only computer is asking for trouble, since ***when*** a problem occurs (as you've encountered), the only solution is to use Windows to fix it.

While you're considering this, I recommend you look into the possibility of using a separate `/home` partition, as covered [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142695/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-having-a-separate-home-partition) Various other questions, like [this one,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643441/how-to-create-a-seperate-partition-for-home-after-accidentally-installing-ubuntu) cover the mechanics of creating a separate home partition. I mention this because my hunch is that the data on your NTFS partition would belong, mostly or completely, in your home directory, and for a dedicated Ubuntu machine, IMHO, a separate `/home` partition is a moderate advantage for such a system.

Comment: Installing Windows again is a bad suggestion - Windows doesn't respect other partitions and wipes out the disk clean, leaving itself a single OS, so OP's files will be gone if they do that.  So I'd suggest you get rid of that part.

Comment: I've installed Windows many times to disks that contain other partitions. Although it *could* wipe other partitions, that would happen mainly in the case of user error. (On MBR disks with extended/logical partitions, Windows' partitioning tools tend to wreak havoc, but this type of configuration has become relatively uncommon recently, with the shift away from MBR and BIOS and to GPT and EFI.) I don't know enough about Hisham's setup to rule out one possible solution based on concern over a problem that would be caused by user error or exotic configurations.

Comment: Installing to disk with other partitions typically means that user knows what they're doing. You might know what you're doing, but OP might not. I've learned to never assume user knows everything (at least on this site)

Comment: Can I fix the ntfs issue if I run windows from a USB Drive and fix it from inside windows without installing windows in the Hard Disk?

Comment: @HishamMubarak yes, if you can boot Windows from an external drive, or if you have a Windows repair disc, then you can probably fix it using the `chkdsk /f d:` command, replacing the "d" with the proper drive letter. Of course, you could try my ntfsfix answer and it wouldn't cost you anything, except possibly a working drive...

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Drives utility
2. Select partition
3. Press Settings button
4. In menu click on "Restore File System..."