# How do I make permanent the changing of my /home folder

Tags: home-directory

How do I make permanent the changing of my **/home** folder

I changed the /home folder using this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home
```

It works fine but, when I restart, the change is lost.

¿ How do I make it permanent  ?

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/643441/how-to-create-a-seperate-partition-for-home-after-accidentally-installing-ubuntu

Comment: +1 for command `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home`.Please go via this tutorial. it helped me alot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 2):

For any mount to be permanent, it needs to go in your fstab file.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
```

You can [read this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) if you need more details on how to edit your fstab file.