# How to extend the root partition in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, nvme

I have the following situation:

[image]

Where I would like to extend the size of nvme0n1 from 8GB to 78 GB using the command line.

Adding also fdisk as requested in comments:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using `sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1`

Comment: I ran it and I get "The filesystem is already 2096891 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!"

Comment: First, create a new partition using `sudo fdisk /dev/nvme`, then format it and after all, resize your partition using `resize2fs`.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.
Command (m for help): n
All space for primary partitions is in use.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of `fdisk -l /dev/nvme` to your question.

Comment: Do this carefully. I don't accept any responsibilities for data loss: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime

Comment: Be carefull. It doens't use `fdisk /dev/sda1`, but `fdisk /dev/sda`. So you should use `fdisk /dev/nvme`. To find the correct device, do `ls /dev/nvme*`. I repeat: don't call `fdisk` for a partition, but call it with the whole device.

Comment: I don't think you can do this while the root filesystem is mounted. Why not do this with a livedisk/usb?

Comment: @PonJar It's possible using `Gparted`. I did the same some minutes age.

Comment: @MohammadKholghi please stop suggesting dangerous and/or wrong solutions. You can not expand a mouted filesystem/partition in Ubuntu.

Comment: @SorenA Absolutely Using a live media is the best way, but I did extend my root partition some minutes ago. Just need to run `partprobe` to `inform the OS of partition table changes`, according to last line of `fdisk` output or `man partprobe`. Or, at last, after a normal restart everything will be fine automatically.

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an AWS EC2 instance you are adding a new volume to. You started correctly by listing the available devices.

Then, you need to create a file system on the new device (use `sudo file -s` to check if there is a file system already) with:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Then, make a directory on where you want to mount it:

```
sudo mkdir /mydata
```

And mount it:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mydata
```

Finally, add it to `fstab` for auto mounting by editing `fstab` (back it up first) using:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

with the info from:

```
sudo lsblk -o +UUID
```

Test by unmounting the file system and then mounting it again with the next commands:

```
sudo umount /mydata
sudo mount -a
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot extend your root partition since it’s filling all of the available space on the device `nvme0n1`. If you want to utilize the space of the device `nvme1n1`, you can:

- Use [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) for your root partition. A logical volume can spread across multiple disks using LVM. However, this would need reinstalling your system or backing it up, preparing LVM volumes and restoring current data.
- Use `nvme1n1` for a partition below your root, e.g. a separate `/home` or `/var` partition.

### See also

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452135/54675 for NVMe device naming
- [How to create a separate home partition after installing Ubuntu under single / partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643441/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu-under-single-p)