# Moving home folder location

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

To put this as simply as possible, I know nothing about Linux and every guide I've seen is extremely confusing and most times doesn't work.

I want to burn a windows 7 ISO onto a flash drive because Ubuntu is way to complicated for me and my original windows system got corrupted and deleted. The problem is that my portioning got screwed up when I installed ubuntu and my home partion has almost no storage (something around 10 gb I think), the ISO is downloaded on a separate partion/disk (which has 500gb of storage); Unetbootin wont let me use ISOs from other disks. I can't bring the ISO over to my current partion because it's full. I need to move everything from my current partion onto the partion that has the 500gb of storage. What do I do.

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: you can use Imaging or disk-managment software to do so, however it will take less time if you re-install everything instead

Comment: See my answer there on how to move home to another partition from command line: https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Answer (score 0):

Your best option to create a bootable Windows 7 USB is by using Rufus, that needs a Windows computer though. And for transferring data, a Ubuntu live DVD/USB will do the job. You just need an external USB drive to copy your necessary data and copy those back to your new Windows installation, wherever you want. Hope I could make out your issue correctly. Regards