# How do I use /dev/sdb1 to reduce the strain on /dev/sda1

Tags: filesystem, files, disk-usage

I have the following setup :

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1009440       4   1009436   1% /dev
tmpfs             205004    1076    203928   1% /run
/dev/sda1       10189112 8848004    800488  92% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1025016      72   1024944   1% /run/shm
none              102400       4    102396   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       20510332 9607008   9838416  50% /media/poloextra
```

I would like to make use of some of the space on /dev/sdb1 to install more programmes (using apt-get). What's the best way to do this ?

In the past, and when I've only been interested in data, I've created a directory in, for instance the root like this /mydatadir, and then created a symbolic link from there into the file system with more room.

I'm just not sure how to apply that idea to getting more space for installing software ? Or maybe there is a better approach ?

Comment: You could move your /home directory to /dev/sdb1. First, find out if it will fit: `sudo du -sh /home`

Comment: @Jos OK thanks for the suggestion. There is room to move /home to /dev/sdb1 . Is this http://askubuntu.com/a/50539/257420 (starting from "Copy HOME to the new location") a reasonable approach to doing the move ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is, but only if you are prepared to sacrifice the whole partition `/dev/sdb1` to /home. From the listing above, I notice that the disk `/dev/sdb1` is currently 50% in use. In the scenario you linked to, you would lose that data. If you don't want to lose that data, then refer to the first answer to that question.