# After changing drive for $HOME can't run Teamviewer

Tags: wine, teamviewer

I wanted to changed the location of my $HOME directory from a 200 GB SSD to a 2 TB SATA. I did it according to the second answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539#50539?newreg=5ad9b367cc2d4ab49a2f05f436caba83). Now Teamviewer will not start any more. I if I try to start it by just clicking the icon, nothing happens. If I try it from the terminal by typing `teamviewer` I get following message:

```
Init...
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
wine: /home/adminuser/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you
wine: /home/adminuser/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you
```

Of course I checked if my account has permission to use teamviewer, and it does. Why was there no issue before, and now there is?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chown -R adminuser:adminuser /home/adminuser/.local/share/teamviewer11`?

Comment: yes I tried that already, I saw that goolging for some common wine issues. Sorry for not mentioning it. Also the owner is always root. I tried to change it to standard user, but it just automatically changes back to root. I read that wine has issues with root being the owner?

Comment: Did you restart `teamviewerd` after that?

Comment: I tried it with `kill -HUP teamviewer` but it fails: `kill: failed to parse argument: 'teamviewer'`

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart teamviewer` on modern Ubuntus, or `sudo service teamviewer restart` should work.

Comment: I get this `teamviewer: unrecognized service`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44408/discussion-between-vaxin-and-jos).

Comment: What **filesystem** the new drive formatted as (where you moved the home directory)?

Comment: It is in ntfs format. I added `UUID=7D7CEF726B6E2A2B   /home   ntfs    defaults        0       2` to /etc/fstab

Comment: Using an NTFS filesystem for your home directory is not recommended, for the exact reasons you are discovering (it doesn't properly handle Linux file ownerships/permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steeldriver mentioned that Ubuntu does not run well on a NTSF formatted filesystem. So I backed up my hard drive, changed $HOME to the back up drive and formatted my drive to ext4. Then I copied everything back to my now ext4 formatted drive. It still did not work right away. Here is how it fixed it:

1. Uninstall teamviewer `sudo apt-get remove teamviwer`
2. Download and install the latest .deb file from teamviewer offical home page.
3. Still did not work. Now I changed ownership in the .config folder again:

   `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/teamviewer`
4. Then in the .local/share/ folder:

   `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.local/share/teamviewer11`

That did it for me. I changed ownership using chown several times but it did not work. Formatting my drive to ext4 and reinstalling teamviewer did it though.

Thank you guys.