# Ubuntu goes into emergency mode after I moved /home dir

Tags: boot, 16.04

I need help with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install. The installation went without any problem. After it, I moved my /home directory to larger disk. Ubuntu was installed onto small 24 Gb SSD. I moved /home according to this manual [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive).
Everything went smoothly, I was able to login and it worked(I rebooted it, shut it down and turned it on again) ok for a day. But after one of the reboots my system booted into an emergency mode. Rebooting obviously didn't help.

I executed `journalctl -xb` to get logs. Here is a picture:
[image]

I tried loading with Live CD. I could access my home directory at the second drive.

Edit: I tried to reinstall it and move /home again. Exact same problem immediately.

Edit 2: running sudo fsck /dev/sda1 fixed all my problems. Thank you

Does someone have any advice please? Thank you

Comment: Did you run a `fsck` manually, as is suggested?

Comment: show us the content of `/etc/fstab` and output of `sudo blkid` comand.

Comment: Ok, I guess I am an idiot. I tried running fsck manually before and it suggested to create new partition table and format my drive doing it. I tried running it again now and it fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to repair things by using a Live Media to repair the `/etc/fstab` entry that points to /home, so it references the correct volume.