# How to change the default home directory?

Tags: home-directory, useradd

On a server, I have mounted a big drive on `/home2` in order to store all the user accounts.

Supposedly in order to set the default directory to `/home2`, we are supposed to edit /`etc/default/useradd`

Inside is a line (commented out)

```
#HOME=/home
```

which I change to:

```
HOME=/home2
```

Yet subsequently, `useradd -m` continues to create users home directories in `/home`.  For the moment, I just mounted the new drive as `/home`, and that did work obviously.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Comment: Did you uncomment the line in the `/etc/default/useradd` when you made the change to it?

Comment: Show us a `diff  /etc/default/useradd useradd.backup`. You did keep a backup of the only working copy you know of, right?

Comment: nope.  It's a brand new system, no one is on it, and it never occurred to me.  And it's one line.  I will have to do this Tuesday, I can't reach it now.

Comment: yes, I did uncomment the line
#HOME=/home
becomes
HOME=/home2

Comment: `adduser` seems to ignore the `useradd` setting. `useradd` uses the location specified in the configuration file but `adduser` simply ignores it