# How to configure locations of installed applications on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning

I've just started using Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus ROG with two hard disks, SSD+HDD. I am a beginner at using Ubuntu. 
The SSD has only 100GB space and I heard from somewhere that it's not polite to such device to overwrite it often. That's why I want to install all programs such as Chrome, VirtualBox, etc. on the HDD (I mounted it at `/media/user`). How can I configure it?

Results of `df -h` :

```
user@muzalevsky:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  3.5M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdb4       106G   61G   39G  61% /
tmpfs           5.9G   21M  5.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2       477M  4.7M  472M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2       820G   29G  750G   4% /media/user
tmpfs           1.2G   20K  1.2G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           1.2G   52K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: You can write and rewrite on your ssd. He's lifetime is longer than your asus pc

Comment: ok but what the main thing is that it has 100 GB which is not much... and actually i have no idea what is in my home at the moment. I already used 61%(

Comment: 61%?! Not from installing software... to fill up 25Gb you need to install so many software you'd better rethink your installation policy ;) If that 61Gb is including /home/ ... put your private documents on the hdd and not the ssd.

Comment: `/media/user` why? I would expected a personal partition and not /media as this is for detachable disks.  If that is detachable and NTFS formatted you are never going to get Ubuntu software working on that.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing all applications on the SSD. SSDs have no moving parts and are more reliable and have a longer life expectancy than HDDs. If disk space on the SSD is at a premium, you can save valuable disk space on the SSD by configuring the default locations of the guest OSs in VirtualBox to be on the HDD. In addition you don't need to store much data in your `/home` directory on the SSD. In order to free up space on the SSD, files that take up a lot of space such as your music library can be stored on the HDD instead. Another way of saving space on the SSD is to move your entire `/home` directory from the SSD to the HDD by following the instructions in the answers to: [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive).

You can use [custom folders](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories) for folders in /home/. Example:

```
 xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD /media/user/Downloads/
```

would switch from /home/$USER/Downloads/ to /media/user/Downloads/ and documents downloaded would then download to the HDD and not the SSD. Same applies for all the other directories. See `~./config/user-dirs.dirs` on manually editing these settings.

Comment: /home: only the directories is enough and there is a setting for that: `~/config/user-dirs.dirs`. The config in /home benifits from the speed of the ssd.

Comment: Please edit my answer and copy/paste your comment into it.

Comment: hey I upvoted and now you want me to maintain it too? >:-D