# How to reallocate disk partition?

Tags: partitioning

I've a 500GB Disk with Linux and Windows installed. I've given 30GB to Linux. So windows has 470GB now. How to increase the space of 30GB of Linux in Ubuntu from the 470GB windows?

Answer (score 3):

You should first boot in to Windows.

1. Start the Disk Management Tool.
2. Select your Windows disk and right click it.
3. Choose to shrink it.
4. The amount of space you shrink it, will be the available new free space.

Reboot your computer to Ubuntu.

1. Start GParted.
2. Resize your 30GB partition. Or format the free space as antoher ext4-partition.

Comment: Further you can move the `/home` directory on that new ext4 partition: https://askubuntu.com/a/50539/566421 ... because 30GB are enough for the OS.