# Keep /home on HDD and move other files into an SSD

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssd, home-directory, boot-partition

I installed Ubuntu on my HDD, there are two partitions on HDD: ~2TB with ext4 (sda1) format and 8GB for swap (sda2).

There are a lot of files in the `/home` directory but it is not separated. I did add a new SSD (sdb) into my PC.

**How can I keep `/home` in HDD and move everything else into the new SSD?**

distro: Ubuntu desktop 18.04.4 LTS (Gnome shell)
HDD Size: 2.0 TB (2,000,398,934,016 bytes)
/home directory on HDD size: 80GB

I'm not using any virtualization and hibernation.

Comment: @k7aay, thanks. I checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive), As I said I want to keep my /home on HDD.

Comment: Thank you but the swap is not the matter, I want to move everything except /home from 2TB HDD to a new 240GB SSD to speedup my PC.

Comment: What's the total of file space on the 2TB HDD now, less the file space used by /home ? Please answer with [edit] and please don't answer with Add Comment.

Comment: But home and all of Ubuntu also fit on the new SSD?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Comment: @dessert The linked topic does not fully cover this problem as OP needs to move the _system_ in this case, i.e. keep it bootable after moved to the other drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want but it’s always best to backup your data first.

Since you only have 80GB in your home directory I would be inclined to do the following:

1. Shrink your system partition (including home) so it’s smaller than your SSD.
2. Clone the HDD to the SSD and get it booting
3. Delete the HDD partition and make a new partition on the HDD
4. Copy the home directories to the new partition
5. Sort out FSTAB so the new home is mounted and delete the old home

Ask or search here if you don’t know how to complete these steps