# Move home folder to NTFS partition ubuntu 20

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, home-directory

I want to move `/home` to a NTFS drive on Ubuntu 20.0 LTS. I tried the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive), but it fails after the following steps:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/tmp
sudo rsync -avx /home/ /mnt/tmp
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

The following message is shown:

```
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Can `/home` be moved to an NTFS drive like this on Ubuntu ?

Comment: Even if that's possible, that's not a good idea imo.

Comment: Try unmounting sdb1, then mount it again at /home. You will need to change fstab if you want this to be permanent. There are a lot of configuration files in hidden directories under /home. If you do this occasionally expect some configuration issues although there may be greater problems too. Not recommended imo.

Comment: Personally I have created submount in /home/user/Windows and mounted D: partition here for communication with windows.