# How to move a program from SSD to HDD on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: files, ssd

If I install a program from the terminal, it will be installed in the default folder of the system, right?

But how can I change this folder, in order to install stuff to HDD instead of SSD ?

Also, how can I change the folder of a program that is already installed ?

Comment: Give the name of the program you want to move. The commands may be different for different programs. Also are both the HDD internal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Comment: maybe stupid questions from me. Why? Not enough space?

Comment: It CAN be done, but generally should not. It's not a trivial process and it's not easy for a beginner to maintain. Very un-Windows-like.

Comment: if you want to install it elsewhere install from SOURCE and use /opt/. Otherwise stick to the defaults.