# Use other volumes space for root

Tags: partitioning

I have a too limited space for home so I get regular pop up to ask me to increase its size
[below an image of the scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85LPs.png)

I have several discs, on one of them is the Windows OS, but still I have plenty of extra space on some of them. How can I move the partitions so I will improve the situation of root?[the different discs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyd0j.png)
I do not wish a priori to move home to another drive I would prefer to reduce the size of one disc, sda2? sdc1?, to increase that of "computer".
Here is the output of `lsblk -f -e 7`

> NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
> sda
> ├─sda1
> │    ntfs   Réservé au système
> │                 B222C07022C03ADD
> └─sda2
> ntfs         1E68C1B868C18F49
> sdb
> ├─sdb1
> │    vfat         628D-C50C
> └─sdb2
> ext4         bd63daef-32db-4142-899c-102b010bafba
> sdc
> └─sdc1
> ntfs   data  9AE2DF57E2DF366B
> sdd
> ├─sdd1
> │    ntfs   Réservé au système
> │                 6EF4EB87F4EB503F
> ├─sdd2
> │    ntfs         60E6EC51E6EC28CC
> ├─sdd3
> │    vfat         1D60-F3AA                             506,8M     1% /boot/efi
> ├─sdd4
> │
> └─sdd5
> ext4         7c8530db-d558-4564-9630-2bed16d579dd    3,3G    82% /

Comment: Does this answer your question? (This answer also covers: "Move home to another partition") [Move home folder to second drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Comment: You might get more suggestions if you add the output of the `lsblk -f -e 7`terminal command to your question. We cannot see on what device “Computer” is located.