# Installing Ubuntu kernel and userspace on different disks?

Tags: partitioning, kernel

I have an Aurora R7. Ubuntu is the only OS on the computer.

I have a problem. I installed the distro to the Intel mempak which is for Intel optane. It is 16GB.

Is there a way to install the kernel space on the 16GB mempak drive and the user-space onto a separate 1TB SSD that I have?

Details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
Release: 22.04 
Codename: jammy
Desktop version, full graphical capabilities
```

Desired Outcome:

- Have the kernel installed on the 16GB optane mempak.
- Have all additional files be saved on the separate 1TB SSD.
- All new additions to the filesystem are saved to the 1TB SSD.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: You are best planning your installation to specific directories, and then install using that plan.  Ubuntu Desktop recommends a minimum recommended space of 25GB which you've not met, and movements are more difficult post install; but still possible. You boot *live* media and make the directories on the volume/drives you want, the modify your file-system-table (*fstab*) to reflect the new locations & it's done.  Specific packages install to specific directories, so it's not "additional" apps that will be caught, but ALL. Don't forget *deb*, *snap* etc use different directories.

Comment: There is a very nice answer on this forum: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not totally correct. You can install the system with manual partitioning having `/` on the small disk (16 GB should be enough in most user cases) and `/home` to another disk.

You can re-install Ubuntu this way or move `/home` to another disk now. But if you just installed the system, the first option will be mush easier.